# How to write poem in two languages, one on left and the other on right page

Tags: languages, poetry

How can I have on poem in two different languages written such that in one language it is on the left page and in the other language it is on the right side. Since I have several poems I would like to have in that small book, I thought of the memoir class. 
Is there something available to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that you can use the babel package (indeed you **should**). In the preamble, put this:

```
\usepackage[french,english]{babel}
```

The last one is the one that will be active later. When you need to change the language, use `\selectlanguage`. For example, in your case the most direct (but not best) way to do it may be:

```
 \selectlanguage{english}
 \Large{My poem in english}
 Blablablabla,\\
 Blablablabla,\\
 Blablablabla,\\
 Blablablabla,

 Blablablabla,\\
 Blablablabla,\\
 Blablablabla,\\
 blablablabla...

 \newpage

 \selectlanguage{french}
 \Large{My poem in french}
 Blablablabla,\\
 blablablabla...

 \newpage
```

That should do the trick.

And for the actual poem... well, the best thing (at least the easiest) is to use the `memoir` class as you said. [Look here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24/is-there-a-template-available-that-allows-easy-publishing-of-poem-book) for examples. If you need something even more advanced, [look here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11832/typesetting-a-poem-book-for-manual-binding). Just remember to put `\selectlanguage` before each poem to change the language.

Comment: This doesn't really work. What I'm looking for is a consequent way having left page in one language and the right page in the other. I tried your example, if one poem from one language is larger than one page than it floats the rest to the next page where the other language should be.

Comment: So what you really want is to *merge* two documents, one page per document. The "manual" way to do it will be to directly see how many lines can fit in a page, and then split alternatively the poems. If I figure out a way to do that automatically I'll come back and tell you.

Comment: Pimentel I did not start setting the book, but I did investigate into the above package called parallel. Parallel also has a disadvantage since you need to write the whole poem into the argument of a command, which is bad if you have long text spread over several pages.

Comment: @adnc It seems very interesting, and I think it solves a big part of your problem. Although it is a little *awkward* to write the poem in one argument, it should be no problem to work with several paragraps, just remember to close it at the end. Now there is time to experiment with that package ;)

Answer (score 4):

I found out that the [parallel](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/parallel/) package is also an option to solve two languages on every page.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works beautifully! I will write up more on my solution using this package later on.